# How to determine the gender of a loanword?

Tags: loanword

What if there was a loanword that can't be translated into German, and must remain the same as it was in its original language? Like Lamborghini, for example?

How can you tell the gender of a loanword like that? Is it the way it ends, begins, etc.?

Comment: Car names are usually masculine.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about proper names and for these, the "rule" is to use the same gender as other members of the same class have, if it's not obvious it should be different:

> der Porsche/der AMG/der Melkus
>
> der Lamborghini/der Ferrari/der Maserati

but e.g.

> **die** Corvette/**die** Cobra/**die** Viper/**die** DS/**die** Ente
>
> **das** Kommißbrot/**das** Cremeschnittchen

Comment: I think I understand?? What if the loanword is English, where its words usually don't have genders?

Comment: Use the same gender as other specimens of the **class**. In this case, the class is "car brands" and those are usually male, in German. So it is "der Rolls", "der Bentley" and "der Rover" even if these don't have a gender in English. There are exceptions, and you'll just have to know them. ISTM that the exceptions are often pet names (Vette, Cobra, Viper, Ente, Kommißbrot), not proper brand names.

Comment: @sen: FWIW: Der Chevrolet, der Dodge, der Citroen, der Hanomag, der Renault. But *die* AC Cobra.

Comment: E.g. if it wasn't a car brand, but a motorbike brand, the members of that class are female. So, ***der** BMW* is a car, while ***die** BMW* is a motorbike. Same with *der/die Honda*. For exceptions, e.g. it's *die Corvette* because -ette is a female suffix. (And now think a while why motorbikes are female in German.)

Comment: Even this is inconsistent. It is *die Isetta, die Alfa-Giulietta,* ... but even if their names are feminine we still hear people say ***der** Mercedes* and ***der** Toyota Corolla* ;)